# MySQL insert syntax error from PHP near 'keys,puzzle,posX,posY,map)'

Tags: php, mysql

```php
$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mazegames
        (game,savename,player,playerimg,level,gold,keys,puzzle,posX,posY,map)
    VALUES
        ('$game','$Save','$player','$playerimg','$level','$gold','$keys','$puzzle','$x','$y','$map')",$db);
```

I keep getting this error:

```
Error saving Johnson game. (You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'keys,puzzle,posX,posY,map)
VALUES
('maze','Johnson','Patrick','eddie' at line 2 -- 'maze','Johnson','Patrick','eddie.gif','1','0','0','fail','17','13','w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,b,b,b,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,n,g,g,g,w,g,g,m,g,g,g,m,w,g,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,g,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,w,m,w,m,w,w,w,d,w,w,g,g,w,w,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,g,m,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,n,g,g,d,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,w,w,g,g,w,w,g,w,w,g,g,w,g,w,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,w,m,w,g,g,w,m,g,m,w,g,g,w,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,n,g,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,g,g,w,m,g,a,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,g,g,j,g,g,g,i,g,g,g,j,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,n,g,n,m,w,g,g,w,m,g,m,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,w,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,g,g,g,w,w,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,k,g,g,g,w,k,g,g,g,g,g,g,g,k,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,w,w,w,w,k,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,m,m,w,g,g,g,g,g,g,w,m,g,g,g,d,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,m,w,w,w,w,g,g,g,w,g,g,g,g,w,g,w,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,d,s,d,d,g,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,g,g,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,b,w,w,w,w,w,g,g,w,g,g,g,w,g,g,w,g,g,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,x,w,w,w,w,w,m,g,c,g,g,w,a,g,w,g,g,e,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w,w')
```

I have increased the size of the 'map' column to `VARCHAR (10000)` because I thought I was overrunning the limit of 1000 that I had it set at, but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`keys` is a reserved word, like `SELECT`, `LIMIT` or something else. The correct usage is adding backticks around each field so SQL identifies it.

```
$result2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO mazegames
    (`game`,`savename`,`player`,`playerimg`,`level`,`gold`,`keys`,`puzzle`,`posX`,`posY`,`map`)
VALUES
    ('$game','$Save','$player','$playerimg','$level','$gold','$keys','$puzzle','$x','$y','$map')",$db);
```

Answer (score 6):

`KEYS` is a mysql [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/reserved-words.html). So you need to put backticks around it:

```
gold, `keys`,puzzle
```

Comment: As a general rule, always put backticks around database, table and field names, to identify them as such.

Comment: @Kolink: personally I do that only for reserved words, as long as from my personal point of view they make the queries less readable and maintainable